# Save pg_connect result in php

Tags: php, postgresql

Is it possible to save an opened connection to postgre from pg_connect or it has to open in each php script? Maybe there is another way to work with postgre saving a connection to db in $_SESSION array?

In example $_SESSION['connection'] transforms into INT form RESOURCE after first page reload.

```
<?php
 session_start();

 function bd_connect(){

   $login = $_GET['login'];
   $password = $_GET['password'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['connection']) === false){
        try {

            $connection = pg_connect("
                host=localhost
                port=5432
                dbname=AirQuality
                user=$login
                password=$password
            ");
 
            if(gettype($connection) === "boolean")return "Failed to connect";

            $_SESSION['connection'] = &$connection;
            return "Success";
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return "Connection exists";
 }

 function bd_disconnect(){

    if(isset($_SESSION['connection']) === true){
        try {
            pg_close($_SESSION['connection']);
            unset($_SESSION['connection']);
            return "success";
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return "Connection does not exist yet";
 }

 echo bd_connect()."<br>";
 echo bd_disconnect();
```

Comment: Create persistent connection with PHP on PosgreSQL....? Is what you search to do...?

Comment: yeah,thanks,pg_pconnect is working great and there is another stupid question on stackoverflow...

Comment: There are no stupid questions. And I didn't answer your question but just rephrase your question. You did the rest :)